# I wrote a function that sums the numbers I entered in the inputs, but it didn't work, why?

Tags: javascript

sorry if it's silly.I want to add the numbers I entered in two separate inputs, but it doesn't work.

```
  <body>


  <input type="number" id="number1"/>
  <input type="number" id="number2"/>
  <button onclick="plus()">Sum</button>
 

  <script>


  function plus (){
  let numberbox1 = document.getElementById("number1");
  let numberbox2 = document.getElementById("number2");
  let newnumber =  numberbox1 + numberbox2;
  
  
  let div = document.get.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = newnumber ;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  }

  </script>
```

Comment: you should sum `Element.value`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let div = document.getElementById("num");

function plus (){
  let numberbox1 = +document.getElementById("number1").value;
  let numberbox2 = +document.getElementById("number2").value;
  let newnumber =  numberbox1 + numberbox2;
  console.log(newnumber)
  div.textContent = newnumber; 
   
  }
```

```html
 <input type="number" id="number1"/>
 <input type="number" id="number2"/>

  <button onclick="plus()">Sum</button>
  <div id="num">  </div>
```